# Unable to reference/bind to view template in user control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, view

I have a view template in a user control as below

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Configuration.Views.viewProfileTemplate"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <Grid Background="Azure" Width="233">
        <StackPanel Height="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="stackPanel1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="230">
             <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeProfileText}" Margin="10" />
             <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Profiles}" Height="70" Margin="10"/>
             <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" Height="16" Name="checkBox1" Width="175" />
         </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The user control is defined as below in the main.xaml window

```
<Window x:Class="Configuration.TreeUI"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Configuration.Views"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Configuration"
        Title="TreeUI" Height="300" Width="450" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
```

I atempt to use the template with

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProfileViewModel}">
    <Views:viewProfileTemplate/>
</DataTemplate>
```

But the compiler reports :
Error 1 The type 'Views:viewProfileTemplate' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

I again am missing som important point, but what ?

Going to owe someone a big drink .....

Comment: sorry for typo it should be <views: and not <Views:

Answer (score 0):

There are two potential causes for this:

1) If the data template is in a different assembly than `viewProfileTemplate`, you need to make the xaml reflect this:

```
  xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Configuration.Views;assembly=ViewAssembly"
```

Note that this will also require a reference to be added to the project properly to function.

2) If this is a design time error, make sure to build the solution first.  The WPF designer in VS often will report errors about missing types until you've built once, then it "works" properly.

Comment: OK, the data template is in the code behind the main xaml window [configuration.xaml.cs]. the view template is in a folder [Views] under the main project. Would this produce sperate asemblies?. I did read about this but it did not appear to make any difference, the error is shown at compile time.

Comment: @SarahT No - they'd only be in different assemblies if you had more than one project.

Comment: Sorry Folks Very new to this and did not know I can edit the post, I will consider that a 'telling off' !

Comment: @SarahT Not a problem - I'd just edit your question, and put that in place, so that it looks right.  Without seeing the "real" error, it's tough to help.  (Your error was obviously from when you had it with the typo...)